# Bootstrap3 - image in navbar-brand distorts height

Tags: image, height, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

In Bootstrap3, when an image(which is of less height compared to `navbar`) is included in `navbar-brand`, `navbar` height is distorted(extra space can be seen at the bottom of `navbar`). [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/103041).

Please help to discard bottom space.

Thanks much in advance!

P.S: Image height is 35px and `navbar` height is set to 70px.

Image courtesy: http://www.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the padding in `navbar-brand` (I tried setting it to zero) and erase or re-set the height that `navbar` has, you lose that bottom space.

**Edit**

After the style for `body`, try this:

```
.navbar {
  /* height: 70px; */
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried with - `.navbar-brand { padding-bottom: 0px; }` but, I do not see any difference. Please help with code. Thanks!

Comment: The solution works as expected - removes bottom space but, the logo gets attached to top. Check bootply and please help.

Comment: Excellent! I did try with `padding-top` before commenting but, removed earlier `padding`. Your answer gave a hint. Works fine. Thanks much!

Comment: I did something very similar based on your answer @Zentaurus:  .navbar-brand { padding-top: 13px; padding-bottom: 0; } - and now it no longer is distorted.  Many thanks!